# Jenkins and Git sparse checkouts

Tags: git, jenkins, sparse-checkout

I have a large repository in Git. How do I create a job in Jenkins that checks out just one sub-folder from the project?

Comment: Is it really necessary to add that complexity?  Once the repository is cloned the first time, git would just be pulling new objects.  Unless your jenkins server was lacking sufficient storage, I'd just clone the whole thing and avoid any additional complexity.

Comment: Yes, because in a CI/CD environment, your slaves or Jenkins servers come and go with demand and load...so persistent disk is not there.  Reliance on persistence is valued less than repeatability in many DevOps circles

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) support *sparse checkouts* since git-plugin 2.1.0 (April, 2014). You will need git >= 1.7.0 for this feature.  It is under "Additional Behaviors" -> "Sparse Checkout paths."

[image: screenshot]

See: Jira issue [JENKINS-21809](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21809)

Comment: Unfortunately Git would still need to copy whole repository locally. So you may not experience any speed improvements for Git to get the files from server.

Comment: Unfortunately it still checks it out with the original "path structure" intact, so it's not like it actually checks out "one directory" it just happens to populate only one directory, FWIW

Comment: Quite and old one, but how do we define a subdirectory names with space . I want to checkout "folder/to/include/directory withSpace" ..

Comment: If A is root directory and sparsing to B sub-directory then Sparse checkout path is: `/B/` for B directory. @OK999: Try BackSlash `\ ` before space or any special character in the file or folder name. Example: `/Path/To/My Folder` will be  like `/Path/To/My\ Folder` or try passing path  between quotes "/Path/To/My Folder".

Comment: @luka5z This answer needs to be combined with a shallow clone of depth 1, which Jenkins also supports.

Comment: When you use shallow clone, the list of 'recent changes' shown on the Jenkins job can become inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: @luka5z To avoid copying the while repository, the "git partial clone" feature could be used, but I don't know if Jenkins supports it. It does support cloning only a single branch, so if the repo has multiple branches that take much space, you can save space by cloning only a single branch. Under git settings set the "Refspec" setting under "Advanced"  and under "Advanced clone behaviours" check "Honor refspec on initial clone"

Answer (score 29):

You can use [sparse checkout](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) feature of Git. Note that Git still clones whole repository to local disk. That's not too bad however, because it is compressed.

1. Create a new job in Jenkins, set Git repository in Source Code Management section.
2. Build the project. This will clone whole repository to local disk.
3. Open projects's workspace folder, delete everything there except .git folder.
4. Open Git shell for project's workspace folder. Enable sparse-checkout:

   ```
   git config core.sparsecheckout true
   ```
5. Update working tree:

   ```
   git read-tree -mu HEAD
   ```
6. Create `sparse-checkout` file in .git/info folder. Add path to sub-folder you want to checkout to that file, like so (note trailing slash):

   ```
   folder/to/include/
   ```
7. Build the project again. This time only one sub-folder should appear in workspace folder.

Comment: @RuudLenders Yes, you need to do it for every job that you want to checkout one subfolder only.

Comment: Shouldn't step 5 ´git read-tree -mu HEAD´ follow step 6? As far as I can follow you should first tell Git which files it should look at (step 6) and then read the tree information into the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a custom step that would just use

```
git checkout your-branch -- the/desired/path anthother/desired/path
```

To clear it you could just `rm -rf` the working folder and recreate it with `mkdir workingdir`. This would require you to specify this option on the git level of the above command:

```
git --working-dir="/path/to/workingdir" checkout your-branch -- the/desired/path anthother/desired/path
```

All this depends on how well you know Jenkins.

Comment: The problem is that Jenkins normally uses a plugin to grab source code and Git plugin does not allow you to change the command for checkout.

Comment: I guess writing or modifying an existing plugin would be too much of a problem.