# Jenkins and Git info/sparse-checkout

Tags: git, jenkins, sparse-checkout

I have very large repository in Git and I have created a job in Jenkins that checks out just one sub-folder from the project following this steps [Jenkins and Git sparse checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791472/jenkins-and-git-sparse-checkouts?newreg=1ae24330a4074f61baf8e98fac562953).
The problem is that when i or some of my colleagues Wipe Out Current Workspace from Jenkins, info/sparse-checkout gets deleted too.

How can i fix this issue without having to create info/sparse-checkout every time for the same job?

Comment: when you wipe the WS, it deletes the .git folder. And this is the folder that holds the file for the sparse checkout ".git/info/sparse-checkout"

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21809) Jenkins support ticket it's a recent addition. As I am currently working through this I will try to remember to update on my progress.

[edit] To clarify - Git Sparse Checkout in Jenkins is apparently supported via [Jenkins Plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21809) as of 31/Mar/14.  I have no experience with this plugin to say that it works. However, I am hoping to add this plugin to our Jenkins system soon and report back on its success.

Comment: Please provide a definite answer.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek - The individual was trying to find a way take advantage of sparse checkout with Git inside of Jenkins because the "workaround" presented in another stack overflow article was not working for him. I gave him a link to the Jenkins ticket that provides the recently completed implementation of a Jenkins plugin that does exactly that. My comment afterwards was meant to imply that I have no personal experience that the plugin works as advertised and that I am currently trying to use it as well. Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: Thanks. Try not to post answers if it doesn't solve the question, it's not really an answer, then.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek: It does solve the problem, what isn't clear about that? He can install the newly developed Jenkins plugin that properly supports Git sparse checkout. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is currently not possible with the git plugin alone (maybe you extend it).

I see these two possible solutions:

- You use a plugin ([EnvInject+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) or [pre-scm-buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep)) to execute a shell-script before the SCM checkout. The script have to look like [apenwarrs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/3346021).
- You have a task in Ant/Maven/Grunt/Whatever, which setup the sparse checkout (what I currently do). Setup your Job as usally and execute the new task before all others.