# Run on jenkins grails geb&spock test from repository with two projects

Tags: grails, jenkins, spock, geb

I have in one repository two projects and I want to run one of them with command "test-app :spock  --echoOut". I add a section for grails running [image]

when I run Item then jenkins give me "... does not appear to be part of a Grails application" but I try to run

"test-app :spock --echoOut" in projectDir locally all is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed grails.project.work.dir and Project.Base.Directory
from: /var/lib/jenkins/.grails/2.3.4/projects/MainDir/projectDir
to:  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MainDir/workspace/projectDir

Answer (score 0):

When you have two projects in your repository, what is the layout of it?

Grails in jenkins expect the root of the repo to be the grails application.

If it is not that, you can make a sparse checkout, where you only checkout the subfolder that has the project you need. See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21809

Comment: Is there a command for jenkins in one line to clone projectDir with sparse checkout?

Comment: You can find instructions to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791472/jenkins-and-git-sparse-checkouts