# Get some folders from a large git repo to different directories in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, directory, continuous-integration

I have a large repo and I need to get some folders from it. 
So, this folders should be downloaded to different directories.

Now I'm using `Sparse Checkout paths` for downloading specific folders, but I can't place every downloaded folder to a sub-directory.

For example, I've got:

- `repo/`

  - `foo/something`
  - `foo1/stuff`
  - `client/`

I need to place `repo/foo/` to `src/` and `repo/foo1/` to `cpp/stuff` in Jenkins.

How could I do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24822189/3511167) for a solution. you can do this for multiple folder

Comment: but i need to savet it to different directories

Comment: Make a new build step that moves the directories where you want.