# Load only necessary files in Jenkins Git

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a git project with huge sub-directories history which I don't care for my ci/cd (all I care about is a specific file in ic/ subdirectory and the pom.xml in the root directory).

So I configure Git Plugin with 2 paths as sparse checkouts (. and ic/) but the root is never checked out and the history is loaded anyway!

How can I do to make Git only checkout the files in the root and ic/ directories and not the history of the huge sub-directories?

Btw, I am on a 1.625.3 version of Jenkins with the last compatible version of Git Plugin and I can't change that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you just clone with a shallow depth (`git clone --depth 1`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins and Git sparse checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791472/jenkins-and-git-sparse-checkouts)

Comment: @phd not a duplicate question no

Comment: @FantasticMrFox how do you do that ?

Comment: I tried the "Advanced clone behaviours" setting with "Swallow clone" option checked but it doesn't work, it still loads the entire history!